# Iomega External HDD Not Accessible

Tags: mount, external-hdd

I have an Iomega HDD of capacity 500 GB that works flawlessly on Windows 7, and I own the drive for approximately 3 years. However, I cannot access the disk on Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS. How can I check if the system recognizes the disk and mount it afterwards. I would appreciate any help and guidance you can provide on this matter.

The model number of my drive is 31868600, Ubuntu is 32-bit.

The output of `fdisk -l`:

- Without the HDD attached

  ```
  $ sudo fdisk -l

  Disk /dev/sda: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
  255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
  Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
  Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
  I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
  Disk identifier: 0x07f2837e

     Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
  /dev/sda1              63      212991      106464+  de  Dell Utility
  /dev/sda2   *      212992    41172991    20480000    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
  /dev/sda3        41172992   303323264   131075136+   7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
  /dev/sda4       303323326   976773119   336724897    f  W95 Ext'd (LBA)
  /dev/sda5       303323328   869550254   283113463+   7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
  /dev/sda6       869552128   926437375    28442624   83  Linux
  /dev/sda7       968384512   976773119     4194304   82  Linux swap / Solaris
  /dev/sda8       926439424   968382463    20971520   83  Linux

  Partition table entries are not in disk order
  ```
- With the HDD attached

  ```
  $ sudo fdisk -l

  Disk /dev/sda: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
  255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
  Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
  Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
  I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
  Disk identifier: 0x07f2837e

     Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
  /dev/sda1              63      212991      106464+  de  Dell Utility
  /dev/sda2   *      212992    41172991    20480000    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
  /dev/sda3        41172992   303323264   131075136+   7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
  /dev/sda4       303323326   976773119   336724897    f  W95 Ext'd (LBA)
  /dev/sda5       303323328   869550254   283113463+   7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
  /dev/sda6       869552128   926437375    28442624   83  Linux
  /dev/sda7       968384512   976773119     4194304   82  Linux swap / Solaris
  /dev/sda8       926439424   968382463    20971520   83  Linux

  Partition table entries are not in disk order

  Disk /dev/sdb: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
  255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
  Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
  Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
  I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
  Disk identifier: 0xc5d05dc6

     Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
  /dev/sdb1              63   976768064   488384001    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
  ```

Comment: `fdisk -l` is the easiest way, as its list shows you detail on every drive, mounted or not. Please copy and paste the result into your post above with the edit link under the tags, as well as the result of System -> Administration -> Disk Utitlity

Comment: @K7AAY Thanks for your help the problem is solved now.

Comment: How is solved??

Comment: @Braiam After a reboot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OP wrote:

> [...] the disk worked now after a reboot.